# (My)SQL: group rows by a given field and force the newest data to be used in the grouped row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have an invoices table which stores a history of invoices for every order, so one order can have multiple invoices. 
However in everyday use I only want to select the newest invoice of every order.

An example of two invoices assigned to the same order:

```
invoice_id | order_id | invoice_number | created_at
=====================================================
1          | 42       | 10621          | 2014-05-28
2          | 42       | 10621          | 2014-05-31
```

I tryed the following

```
SELECT * FROM invoices GROUP BY order_id;
```

which groups the rows by the first row it finds, which is the oldest invoice. Adding an 'ORDER BY created_at DESC' clause doesn't change that. 
Is there a way to get only the newest row for each order_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self join on the maximum date of invoice,group by results are indeterminate they can't guarantee the order of results to be grouped below query should do the trick

```
SELECT 
  i.* 
FROM
  invoices i 
JOIN 
  (SELECT 
      order_id,
      MAX(created_at) created_at 
    FROM
      invoices 
 GROUP BY order_id) ii 
ON (
  i.order_id = ii.order_id 
  AND i.created_at = ii.created_at
)
```

Comment: I chose this approach because it is a bit easier to understand for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reasonable way to get the most recent row with your data.  Note that it does not use `group by`:

```
select i.*
from invoices
where not exists (select 1
                  from invoices i2
                  where i2.order_id = i.order_id and i2.created_at > i.created_at
                 );
```

If performance is a concern, you will want an index on `invoices(order_id, created_at)`.

This version changes the question from "Get me the invoice with the biggest date for each order" to "Get me the invoice for each order such that no other invoice for that order has a larger date".

Comment: An interesting approach, but I think it's a bit difficult to comprehend what the query is actually doing if you stumple upon the code the first time.